# Overriding Cache-Control Header on Azure Websites

Tags: azure, iis, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I have a Ghost blog hosted on Microsoft Azure. I want to make sure that I can set the `Cache-Control` header myself, because right now it has a `max-age` set to 0.

The way I am approaching this problem is through dropping a custom `web.config` (since Azure Websites uses IIS). Here is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
        </modules>
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" />
        </staticContent>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <remove name="Cache-Control" />
                <add name="Cache-Control" value="public, max-age=99" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

However, this does not actually remove the original `Cache-Control` header, but rather appends my value to it:

[image]

Any insights on what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is more trivial than I originally thought. While I was properly setting the headers in `web.config`, the server node.js configuration was enforcing its own `Cache-Control` rule, that was overriding mine.

In `\core\server\middleware` there is a file called `cache-control.js`. Inside it there is a snippet:

```
cacheControl = function cacheControl(options) {
    /*jslint unparam:true*/
    var profiles = {
            public: 'public, max-age=0',
            private: 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0'
        },
        output;
```

All I needed to do is tweak `'public, max-age=0'` to the value I wanted.

This eliminated the need for `web.config` altogether.